# Applying modifiers in a script

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I've seen a couple of good examples of creating modifiers and applying them to objects, but they don't seem to be working for me. Or at least are only working part way.

My function takes a modifier type (in my test case, `'UNION'`) and a list of objects. The first object is the `target` and the rest are going to be the modifications.

When this executes, my target still has the stack of modifiers attached to it. I have to manually push the *Apply* button in the UI for each one. How can I make that happen in my script?

```
def applyModifier (self, mod, items):
    target = items[0]
    for i in range(1, len(items)):
        objB = items[i]
        boo = target.modifiers.new('Booh', 'BOOLEAN')
        boo.object = objB
        boo.operation = mod
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Booh")
        bpy.context.scene.objects.unlink(objB)
    return target
```

The subordinate objects do unlink from the scene, so I know that bit of code is executing properly.

Comment: Have a look at `Object.to_mesh()`: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=to_mesh#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh If you want to apply all modifiers, then it's probably the better way. Nonetheless, `bpy.ops` can be the better (or only) choice in certain use cases.

Comment: That one looks interesting, too. I'll give it a shot. One of the frustrations with Blender seems to be that there are multiple ways of accomplishing things, but the advantages and disadvantages aren't always clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're using something from `bpy.ops`, you need to get the editor state right (this is the failing of most of `bpy.ops`).

You probably need to set `bpy.context.scene.objects.active = target`

and in 2.8+

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = target
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid bpy.ops to apply a modifier?