# How can I put a modifier at the top of the modifier stack?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I have a modifier that I want to put at the top of the modifier stack.

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have two modifiers like this:

[image]

Note that the second modifier is named "Subsurf".  You can move it up like this:

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up(modifier="Subsurf")
```

You may need to set the active object first, as described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15588/14029):

```
my_object = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = my_object
```

If your modifier is in an unknown position in the stack, you can use a loop like this to bring it to the top:

```
while my_object.modifiers[0].name != "Subsurf":
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up(modifier="Subsurf")
```

Comment: But what if I have an unknown number of modifiers?

Comment: @OmarAhmad I edited my post to answer this question.