# How to move modifiers of multiple objects up or down?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I would like to move a modifier (which I have already identified) to the bottom of the list of existing modifiers. Unfortunately it does not work and I don't get why...? However, if the object is *active*, it moves perfectly to the bottom:

```
#ob = my object, not necessarily it must be selected, it is found by a function
#smooth = #my modifier (found through a function)
for m in ob.modifiers:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_down(modifier = smooth.name)
```

This only works if the active object is `ob`. Do I have to override the context? There is a [similar question to this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90342/context-is-incorrect-python-error-while-script-moves-modifier-up-in-modifier) but I have no idea how to apply this in my case.

---

It seems that I have solved my problem by overriding the context members:

```
for m in ob.modifiers:
    c = {}
    c["object"] = c["active_object"] = ob
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_down(c ,modifier = smooth.name)
```

Any thoughts? Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: I guess you mean to the top right? See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/98891/31447

Comment: Ty @brockmann I had already taken a look at this question, but I see that it is practically the same thing that I am doing, the problem is precisely that bpy.ops seems not to work if the object is not active and selected . Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: [WiP... A comprehensive list of operator overrides](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248275/60486)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6105/31447) by passing the actual object `{'object': obj}` to [`bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=modifier_move_up#bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up) or  [`bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_down()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=modifier_move_down#bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_down) operator.

Example on how to move all subdivision modifiers by name *(they are usually called 'Subdivision')* of multiple objects to the top *(position 0)* in the modifier stack:

```
C = bpy.context
mod_name = "Subdivision"

for obj in C.selected_editable_objects:
    # Test whether there is a modifier called "Subdivision" at all 
    if any(m for m in obj.modifiers if m.name == mod_name):
        # Iterate through all modifiers in reverse
        for mod in reversed(C.object.modifiers):
            # Move the modifier as long as its position is 0
            while obj.modifiers.find(mod_name) != 0:
                bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up({'object': obj}, modifier=mod_name)
```

Related questions:

- [Move modifier to the top of the stack through python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/98891/31447)?
- [How can I put a modifier at the top of the modifier stack?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46646/31447)