# How to make a through hole using inward extrusion in Blender 2.8?

Tags: extrude

I am trying to make a through hole using inward extrusion.
I enterd into edit mode, then I drawed an outline of my hole using knife tool.[image]

then I turn into wireframe shading, rotate my view an select snap to faces and then extrude the hole outline inward
[image]

so the hole is created successfully, but I still have a face at the hole bottom.
I can select this face separately
[image]

But If I try to delete it, I siply delete this face (I can't select it anymore after deleteting), but I do not see through hole, so the basic cube face is still here.
So how to remove the hole bottom?

Comment: it is possible that this "[swiss cheese modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62642/5334)" might be helpful to look at, though it's a script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the faces of a mesh to dig a hole in the same mesh, using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Intersect (Boolean)* tool. Just push the face a bit further down. Then in the *Operator* box choose *Difference* and *Solver > Fast*.

[image]

Or use a second mesh:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, mate, solved it! Pictures too!? y'sh'dna <3