# Making a Trypophobia-triggering image In Blender

Tags: mesh

> **[Trypophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypophobia)** is an aversion to the sight of irregular patterns or clusters of small holes or bumps

Is there an easy way, such as a modifier, to make a "trypophobic" mesh?

Comment: Well there is obviously no Trypophobia modifier. Google Trypophobia, look around if someone else has done a tutorial on it and try to model it yourself, if you have a problem along the way, that you can't solve, you're welcome to ask about that. At the moment your question lacks any effort

Comment: I did look it up, I couldn't find anything. t-t

Comment: I usually use the trypophobia add-on

Comment: Could you please make the title more descriptive? You cannot "make" a phobia in a graphics program.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! Each of them is awesome and works very well. :>

Comment: for a literal "cluster of small holes" see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62616/5334

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### [Tissue addon](https://blenderartists.org/t/tissue-by-alessandro-zomparelli/646071)

Another possibilty would be to use the Tissue add-on.
You basically define a "component", in this case a little hole with a protruberance (the one outlined in orange) and spread it on the faces of a base mesh (suzanne, outllined in light orange).

Run the Tessellate option with the objects selected in this order, enable the merging option and then run the subsurf modifier on the result to smooth the "component".

[image]

The cool thing is that you can use whatever shape as input component.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The subsurface scattering really makes it disgusting. Well done!

Comment: Hahaha, thakns!

Comment: That looks incredible, can you animate the input shape?

Comment: Yes, with shape keys, but there is currently an issue with the refreshing during Render Animation that prevent a correct usage. We'll have to wait an update for the fixing.

Comment: That second one is nightmare material for me, thanks for making me shudder...

Comment: thanks, I hate it

Answer (score 20):

A quick and dirty solution you can achieve without too much work is

1. Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with enough iterations
2. Add a *Decimate modifier* with a high ratio set to *Triangulate*
3. Add a *Wireframe modifier*
4. Add another *Subdivision Surface* modifier

[image]

Results won't be the best, but it is quick and non destructive.

Comment: Tysm! This is awesome and easy! :>

Comment: Take it away it  has tripped my _crochet-phobia_

Comment: @batFINGER Lol, I can see where you're coming from. XD

Comment: My son has this phobia.  To be honest, the sample image you have displayed in your answer wouldn't trigger him.

Comment: There are online services that will turn any shape into a  Voronoi model. This might be even easier.

Answer (score 18):

**A pox on Suzanne.**

**WARNING:** If you  are Trypophobic look way now.

[image]
*Run on default Suzanne, subsurf modifier added later*

In putting together test scripts for the must have [Trypophobia addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165249/making-trypophobia-in-blender#comment279242_165249) The wiki page uses an illustration of lotus flower as an example.

> [image] The holes in lotus seedheads
>   elicit feelings of discomfort or repulsion

which looks to me like a bit of an inset extrude arrangement, as a mesh

[image]
*Run on default UV sphere, subsurf modifier added later*

Sneak peek draft code to produce effect above. Selects 70% of quad or ngon faces and pimple-izes them. Running again produces results that are too dangerous to post here.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from random import randint, uniform

face_percent = 0.7

context = bpy.context
# test on suzzamne
#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add()
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
#bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
faces = set()
nontris = [f for f in bm.faces if len(f.verts) > 3]
while len(faces) < face_percent * len(nontris):
    faces.add(nontris[randint(0, len(nontris) - 1)])


for i in range(2):
    for f in faces:
        ret = bmesh.ops.inset_individual(bm,
            faces=[f],
            thickness=uniform(0.1, 0.2),
            depth=uniform(0.1, 0.4),
            use_relative_offset=True,
            ) 

ret = bmesh.ops.inset_individual(bm,
    faces=list(faces),
    thickness=0.5,
    depth=-0.5,
    use_relative_offset=True,
    )

#bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=list(faces), context='FACES')
bm.to_mesh(me)
```

Comment: This is what nightmares are made of... Just, why? Poor Suzanne.

Comment: Once again the master of scripting in action. This is awesome for crater ridden surfaces, great work

Comment: As someone with Trypophobia, this one makes me significantly more uncomfortable than the other two answers.

Answer (score 10):

For a pretty much one button approach that comes with some other sometimes useful things there is an add-on called BY-GEN that essentially creates various procedural modifiers stacks and duplivert effects for you based on the effect you choose.

This particular one would be *Organic Shell*. I changed displacement type to voronoi, it seems to work better in this case.

[image]

This is the modifier stack that is generated by this particular choice of effect:

[image]

The add-on is free on Gumroad last I checked, it works for 2.79 and 2.8x. The link following is to [BlenderNation](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/06/30/by-gen-generative-modeling-toolkit-new-features-for-version-3/), where is a bit more explanation about the tool from the code author.

Render result with the tool:

[image]

Comment: such a nice material too!

Comment: @Luciano You can create such a material easily by sliding the subsurface scattering in the Principled BSDF Shader to 1

Comment: @WhatAMesh yep, pretty close to what it is.

Comment: This wouldn't trigger my son's trypophobia.  However, it might trigger my spouse's snake phobia.