# Making a crater on a sphere surface

Tags: modeling

[image]

I want to make these small extruding craters illustrated in the image, but I never ever touched sculpting section so I have no idea where to start with.

Could you suggest how to make those craters on sculpting mode, or any alternative ways to get the same result?

Comment: it will be cleaner if you use modeling instead of sculpting, and you have a lot of tutorials on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+hole+in+sphere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do away with sculpting, create it from a base icosphere instead.

Add an icosphere, subdivide it as necessary (about 2 in the example below), then on top of it add a *Subdiv Modifier* and set shading to smooth.

Then in *Edit Mode* select clusters of contiguous faces, spaced wherever you want craters to be.

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude them with the option *Along Normals*, followed by a small *Inset* for the ridges, then another final *Extrude Along Normals* to create the depression.

Repeat for more craters, you can adjust crater radius either by insetting once before the first extrusion, or by scaling the extruded faces after the first extrusion.

[image]

Comment: [**Caution** May trigger trypophobia](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165249/making-a-trypophobia-triggering-image-in-blender)

Comment: Indeed, had totally forgotten about that answer, but this did seem familiar

Comment: don't think that answer so well... many sizes and positions for the craters... but ok we'll see when OP reacts

Comment: Thanks a lot for the gif, this answer is exactly what I needed! :))